# Can I write an app for Android/Ubuntu Phone and openly recommend Ubuntu as a software platform legally?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, development, license

I am a developer planning to write an app for a local high school.  This app will most likely be a free/open source program made on Ubuntu.  I am also planning on openly recommending Ubuntu to all users who download the app.  I just want confirmation that the name and logo can be used openly.  If not, I would like a way to contact Canonical and put in a request to use the name/logo of Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: See http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this link](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy), we read that:

- *You can use the Trademarks, in accordance with Canonical’s brand guidelines, with Canonical’s permission in writing. If you require a Trademark licence, please contact us (as set out below)*.
- *You will require Canonical’s permission to use: (i) any mark ending with the letters UBUNTU or BUNTU which is sufficiently similar to the Trademarks or any other confusingly similar mark, and (ii) any Trademark in a domain name or URL or for merchandising purposes.*
- *You cannot use the Trademarks in software titles. If you are producing software for use with or on Ubuntu you may reference Ubuntu, but must avoid: (i) any implication of endorsement, or (ii) any attempt to unfairly or confusingly capitalise on the goodwill of Canonical or Ubuntu.*
- *You can use the Trademarks in discussion, commentary, criticism or parody, provided that you do not imply endorsement by Canonical.*
- *You can write articles, create websites, blogs or talk about Ubuntu, provided that it is clear that you are in no way speaking for or on behalf of Canonical and that you do not imply endorsement by Canonical.*

From which we can conclude that any suggestion that you act *on behalf of*, or any suggestion of 
*interrelationship* or *endorsement* is not allowed.

In my opinion, the *combination* of presenting (your own) software, and making recommendation(s) to use Ubuntu is unavoidably suggesting *some* kind of relationship or endorsement, even if you would specifically say there isn't.

The bottom line is that I wouldn't mix the two. If you however still would like to do so, I would apply to this rule:

- *You can use the Trademarks, in accordance with Canonical’s brand guidelines, with Canonical’s permission in writing. If you require a Trademark licence, please contact us ([as set out below](http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/contact-us)).*